# How can I hit WSO2IS /userinfo endpoint with self-contained (JWT) access token?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm having an issue hitting the `/userinfo` endpoint on WSO2IS when using the self-contained access token as the bearer token. I get back in the response header `Bearer token= 'invalid token'`.

Is there a config setting that I can add to WSO2IS that will allow the use of a self-contained access token that's in JWT format (not UUID format) to hit the `/userinfo` endpoint?